# Can Javascript on client side access Struts form?

Tags: javascript, forms, struts

In Struts say we define some form with the name `TaskForm` in `struts-config.xml`.

In one of the javascript function, I can see the statement:

```
document.TaskForm(some form name in struts-config.xml).action = action
```

My question here is how come we are able to execute `document.taskform` at client side?

I mean statements like `document.getElementByid("")` are defined in browser side but not sure about `document.taskform`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't access Struts ActionForms using JavaScript!**

What you are seeing is JavaScript interaction with the HTML client side `<form>` tag ([something like this tutorial](http://www.openjs.com/tutorials/advanced_tutorial/forms.php) presents)

The HTML `<form>` tag happens to have the same attribute `name` and `action` value as the ones from the `<form-bean>` and `<action>` tags of `struts-config.xml`.
**This is no coincidence!**

`ActionForm`s are the server side object representation of a client side HTML `<form>` tag and [Struts server tags](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html) generate HTML which is then sent to the client.

The HTML `<form>` tag usually contains the name of the  bean specified in `<form-bean>` of `struts-config.xml` tag, while the `action` attribute of the `<form>` is the one specified in the corresponding `<action>` of `struts-config.xml`.

Some names and values are preserved to maintain clarity of the code. This makes things homogeneous. But we are NOT talking about the same thing!